# IONIC 3: Push notification click do nothing

Tags: firebase, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 application and have to implement the push notification in my app. Everything working fine notification comes on my mobile and even if app is running, `on('notification')` triggering well. But problem is, when app not in running state (in background) and when notification arrives and on click notification `on(notification)` not triggering.

**app.component.ts**

```js
pushSetup(){
    const options: PushOptions = {
       android: {
            senderID: '********'
       },
       ios: {
           alert: 'true',
           badge: true,
           sound: 'false'
       }
    };

    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
        console.log(notification);
        if(notification.additionalData.type == 'wordpress'){
            this.zoom.authenticate(notification.additionalData.user_id, "user_encrypted_secret").then((res: AuthCallbackResponse) => {
                console.log(res.successful);
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    });

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
        console.log('Device registered', registration);
        this.storage.set('device_token', registration.registrationId);
    });

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
}
```

And my server code from where notification comes:

```js
$optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
        $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20);

        $title = 'WP Registration Request';

        $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($title);
        $notificationBuilder->setBody('New Wordpress Registration Request')
                            ->setSound('default');

        $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
        $dataBuilder->addData(['token' => $registerToken,'type'=>'wordpress','website'=>$request->domain,'mobile'=>$request->mobile,'user_id'=>$model->id]);

        $option = $optionBuilder->build();

        $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
        $data = $dataBuilder->build();

        $token = $model->device_token;

        $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, $notification, $data);
```

on server side i am using Lumen Framework and using `brozot/laravel-fcm` package for send notification.

Can any one tell me whats the wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `content-available` to 1 in your push payload.

Eg:

```
data: {
  additionalData: {
    content-available :  "1"
    priority : "high"
  },
  image : "icon"
  message : "This is sample message"
  sound : "default"
  title : "New Comment"
}
```

[More Information](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#push-message-arrives-with-app-in-background)